# How to make a column Hide in ssrs matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder

I have an ssrs matrix , the design of which looks like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2WT4.png)
When the report is run , My output looks like this  :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA3I4.png)

I am expecting output like this: If the column have no data i want to hide but i used all the visiblity hide expression but no luck
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVKB7.png)

I want to hide the matrix column group hide if the [productshortdesc] value is empty. In the [productshortdesc] column have two value close fund  and ISO-CEF ADJ if any one of the data is not available i want to hide the column group and required the availbale value in the first column